# Does the moon formation theory consider the necessary precision in the angle of ejection of material caused by the collision?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, geophysics

When Newton considered that a projectile fired horizontally at 8km/h from a very high mountain would enter orbit, I suppose that he also understood the importance of the firing angle being strictly horizontal as even an initial inclination of the canyon of 0.1 ° above the horizontal causes the projectile to pass 45 km above the initial point on its first orbital path and that height will continue to be raised with each orbit completed. If the angle is 0.1 ° below the horizontal line the projectile will end up impacting the earth. My question is: Does the theory of the formation of the moon also consider the extreme importance of the delicate balance necessary between orbital speed and angle of expulsion of the material that came off due to the chaotic collision? Because as I can see the accuracy here is fundamental so that the moon orbit has not changed during known human history

Comment: That's not how orbits work. A deflection of 0.1 degrees on a circular orbit doesn't cause a spiral, it turns a circular orbit into a very slightly elliptical orbit.

Comment: when the projectile is fired with an inclination of 0.1 ° on the vertical line we have that in 8Km the projectile reached a height of 14 meters. Since the projectile falls 5m in a second we have a height of 9m gained in 8km. In the next 8km of travel, the projectile will gain another 9m in height as it maintains its initial inclination angle of 0.1 °. This will continue to increase its height to cover the 40075km of earth circumference in its first orbit. (I see no reason why the projectile loses its initial inclination. It only drops 5m every 8km). Please explain if I am wrong.

Comment: In the opposite way if the inclination is 0.1 ° below the vertical, the projectile ends up impacting the earth before completing its first 8km of travel

Comment: The reason the object launched aimed upwards by 0.1° curves back downwards is exactly the same reason it happens for an object thrown by hand; Gravity As it rises, it loses kinetic energy and gains gravitational potential energy. As it falls, the reverse happens.  This happens for any object launched in any direction at a speed lower than escape velocity (neglecting air resistance and tidal effects, etc.); it winds up travelling at least a portion of an elliptical orbit (As per Kepler's 1st Law), not a spiral.

Comment: Kepler described the movement of the planets. He used the mathematical knowledge of his time to find relationships between the data of the astronomical observations obtained by Tycho Brahe and with them they had the ability to compose a heliocentric model of the universe.

Comment: That is, its laws describe the stable elliptical orbits of the planets as they are observed but do not explain how they entered orbit because at that time it was thought that the universe existed forever and did not have a beginning. The current theory of the formation of the moon supposes the impact of another celestial body with the earth in such a way that the material resulting from the collision left the earth with the speed and the right angle to be trapped in a stable orbit around the earth. Earth.

Comment: This is consistent with Newton's theoretical projectile experiment but not with Kepler's laws. Kepler's laws are only there to describe the orbital movement once it is already stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual modelling using hydrodynamic codes with gravity show that it is not very sensitive. See for example this [paper](https://websites.pmc.ucsc.edu/~rcoe/eart206/canup_Moon_Nature_01.pdf), [paper2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7062), [paper3](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s12036-018-9515-8.pdf), [paper4](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/338/6110/1052.full.pdf?casa_token=FV3OyC8YzVQAAAAA:vvcq0vRCO_aLEAp55-MBM49P-meyFfnwNg7XXJbmkifsMgMRZ0MFpSZ_RjiYlhw_h2eqf9qWrLIu) - they all use different models and settings, yet all get a moon in the end.

The initial ejecta had a wide range of orbits but also coalesced in a dissipative way (turning motion into heat), making a body orbiting close and in an elliptic orbit. But since tidal forces between two nearby rotating bodies were very strong this both circularized the orbit and aligned the orbit axis and Earth's rotation axis.

Over time tidal energy transfer also gave the moon more and more of Earth's angular momentum, slowing Earth's rotation and moving the moon further out. While the slow expansion of the moon's orbit is imperceptible over human history it is evidenced by tidal mudstones and coral fossils.